# How can I build on top of lakes?

Tags: factorio

My factory is doing great, except for a large lake right in the middle of it.

Is there any way to fill the lake in to reclaim the space it takes up? Or do my conveyors need to detour around it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the release of version 0.13, researching the **landfill** technology will let you construct a **landfill** item that replaces water with grass. It costs 20 stone to create and builds in half a second.

Unfortunately there is no equivalent item to turn land into water, so be careful not to deprive yourself of locations for water pumps!

Answer (score 8):

Before 0.13 there was no way to cross bodies of water in vanilla Factorio. There were a couple of mods with different solutions.

A lot of players argued that building with the lay of the land is a nice challenge and give your factory "character" and makes it unique.

Other guys just wanted to build a massive factory and then use the mods to help them cross it.

Since 0.13, you can research the "land fill" technology and then use it to replace water with soil.

Comment: care to link to the mods?

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta Here is one https://forums.factorio.com/viewtopic.php?t=4973 , I think Bob's Mods has a way to do it later down the tech tree as well. There is a few others out there, so just keep your eyes peeled. :)